# Function that checks if the element at given position in given array of integers is bigger than its two neighbors

Tags: c++, function, higher-order-functions

Good afternoon All,

Hope you are doing well!

I am a new one here at the forum, as well as into the programming in C++
I have just started studying c++ and would like to get deeper into the functions.
Been searching a lot for the answer itself, however did not find anything.
First I would like to know if my syntax here is correct.
In the below problem i have provided what's asked from me so you could see if i'm in the right direction.

```
/*

Write a Function that checks if the element at given position in given array of
integers is bigger than its two neighbors (when such exist).
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void outcome(int givenIndex)
{

    const int maxn = 10;
    int arr[maxn] = { 10, 9, 7, 41, 14, 20, 22, 55, 43, 10 };
    int comparer = 0;
    int lowerPosition = 0;
    int lowerIndex = 0;
    bool check = true;
    int higherIndex = 0;
    int higherPosition = 0;
    int currentPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxn; i++)
    {
        if (givenIndex == i)
        {
            comparer = arr[givenIndex - 1];
            currentPos = i;
            lowerIndex = arr[givenIndex - 2];
            higherIndex = arr[givenIndex];
            lowerPosition = i - 1;
            higherPosition = i + 1;


            cout << "position: " << lowerPosition << " ,corresponds to element: " << lowerIndex << endl;
            cout << "position: " << currentPos << " ,corresponds to element: " << comparer << endl;
            cout << "position: " << higherPosition << " ,corresponds to element: " << higherIndex << endl;
            cout << endl;
            if (comparer>lowerIndex)
            {

                cout << "element at position " << lowerPosition << " is lower than element at position " << currentPos << endl;
            }
            else
            {

                cout << "element at position " << lowerPosition << " is bigger than element at position " << currentPos << endl;
            }

            if (comparer>higherIndex)
            {

                cout << "element at position " << higherPosition << " is lower than element at position " << currentPos << endl;
            }
            else
            {

                cout << "element at position " << higherPosition << " is higher than element at position " << currentPos << endl;
            }


        }
    }
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int givenIndex = 0;

    cout << "enter the elemet you would like to compare to its neighbours: " << endl;
    cin >> givenIndex;
    outcome(givenIndex);

    return 0;
}
```

Another thing is that i would like to find out here is - is there anyway how those 3 parameters in the function "Outcome" afterwards can be used into another code, outside of it? 
For example those 3 ("current "Pos", `lower Position`, `higher Position` ) parameters i have received, to be included into another function?

Every answer is much appreciated!
Thanks for your help and your efforts in advance!

Comment: Working code that just needs review should be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: `arr[givenIndex - 1];` is in a really bad spot if `givenIndex == 0`. Or `givenIndex == -607428` for that matter. Best to use an unsigned type for anything you use to index an array because the compiler can help you catch bad numbers.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Surprised we don't have a close vote for that.

Comment: You have to consider that not all elements *have* two neighbors. Like those at either end of the array.